# I'm not able to print page with Selenium WebDriver Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to print a several webpages into PDF using the following command

```
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

However, recently, I'm not able to print my page. The print dialogue opens and closes without printing nor saving.

My defaults are:

- Browser Version: '112.0.5615.138'
- Chrome: '112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c11e8cfe3078709382934e3916914-refs/branch-heads/5615@{#936})'

Python code:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, name: str = "default"):
        self.name = name
        self.download_dir = os.path.join(LocalPath.data_dir, self.name + "\\")
        logging.info("Init Driver")
        self.chrome_driver = self.start_webdriver()
        print(self.chrome_driver.page_source)
        logging.info("Driver Opened")

    def start_webdriver(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        #options.add_argument("--disable-print-preview")
        options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
        #options.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')

        settings = {
            "recentDestinations": [{
                "id": "Save as PDF",
                "origin": "local",
                "account": "",
            }],
            "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
            "version": 2,
            "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
        }
        prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
                 'savefile.default_directory': self.download_dir,
                 "download.default_directory": self.download_dir,
                 "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                 "directory_upgrade": True}
        options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=LocalPath.driver_path,
                                  options=options)
        return driver
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using Selenium 4 version of the python bindings. You get access to the ChromeDevTools protocols which allows you to do a host of things (like Network interception, Listening to DOM events, etc.)

You can leverage that to your case and print the pages. All you need to do is enable the Page CDP protocol using the `Page.enable()` method, then browse to the location which you want to print, send the devTools command `Page.print_to_pdf()` (Assuming you need to go with the default print settings). The response from this method would be a base64 encoded string which you'll need to write into a file.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.devtools import page

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
dev_tools = DevTools(driver)
dev_tools.create_session()

dev_tools.send(page.enable())

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

pdf_response = dev_tools.send(
    page.print_to_pdf()
)

with open("C:/file.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(pdf_response['data']))
```

In case, you want to override the default configs the params that you'll need to send are :

```py
pdf_response = dev_tools.send(
    page.print_to_pdf(
        landscape=False,
        displayHeaderFooter=False,
        printBackground=True,
        scale=1.0,
        paperWidth=8.5,
        paperHeight=11.0,
        marginTop=0.4,
        marginBottom=0.4,
        marginLeft=0.4,
        marginRight=0.4,
        pageRanges='',
        ignoreInvalidPageRanges=False,
        preferCSSPageSize=False,
        transferMode=None
    )
)
```

Please note, my primary language of choice is Java. In case, the above code doesn't work. You basically need to write something similar to the below written Java code :

```java
DevTools devTools = ((HasDevTools) browser).getDevTools();
devTools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne();

devTools.send(Page.enable());

browser.get("https://www.google.com");

Page.PrintToPDFResponse response = devTools.send(
    Page.printToPDF(
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.empty()
    )
);

Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\file.pdf"),Base64.getDecoder().decode(response.getData()));
```

You can read about the CDP protocol [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF)